# py2exe No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) and when I try to run setup.py I get this

```
    running py2exe 
    Building 'dist\test.exe'. 
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\py2exe\\run-py3.5-win-amd64.exe'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your python version? `py2exe` does not support Python 3.5, but you can use Python 3.4 or lower.